# Mapa aleatorio con Python3 modulo pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estoy creando un juego de estilo Roguelike con el modulo de pygame. El problema que tengo es que nose como continuar el codigo, los mapas son dibujados en un archivo txt con caracteres(#=puerta,.=vacio,1=pared y p=personaje) solo logre poner 3 cuartos pero nose como continuar el codigo para que se genere un mapa con mas cuartos. Lo estoy haciendo bien o me recomiendan cambiar de forma? adjunto codigos(Aclaracion parte del codigo no es mio)

Main.py

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random
from os import path
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from tilemap import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        self.map = Map(path.join(game_folder, 'map2.txt'))
        self.map2 = Map(path.join(game_folder,'map.txt'))
        self.map3 = Map(path.join(game_folder,'map3.txt'))
        self.total_map_w = 0
        self.total_map_h = 0
        self.previous_w = 0
        self.previous_h = 0

    def create_map(self,mapa,orientation=True):#orientation TRUE == horizontal orientation FALSE == vertical
        if(orientation):
            for row, tiles in enumerate(mapa.data):
                for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                    if tile == '1':
                        Wall(self, col+self.previous_w, row)
                    if tile == '#':
                        Door(self,col+self.previous_w, row)
                    if tile == 'P':
                        self.player = Player(self, col, row)
            self.total_map_w += mapa.tilewidth
        else:
            for row, tiles in enumerate(mapa.data):
                for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                    if tile == '1':
                        Wall(self, col, row+self.previous_h)
                    if tile == '#':
                        Door(self,col, row+self.previous_h)
                    if tile == 'P':
                        self.player = Player(self, col, row)
            self.total_map_h += mapa.tileheight
        self.previous_h = mapa.tileheight
        self.previous_w = mapa.tilewidth

    def new(self):
        # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.create_map(self.map)
        self.create_map(self.map2)
        self.create_map(self.map3,False)
        self.mapwitdh=self.map.width+self.map2.width
        self.mapheight=self.map.height+self.map2.height
        self.camera = Camera(self.mapwitdh,self.mapheight)

    def run(self):
        # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        # update portion of the game loop
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.camera.update(self.player)

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.draw_grid()
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        # catch all events here
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

# create the game object
def main():
    g = Game()
    g.show_start_screen()
    while True:
        g.new()
        g.run()
        g.show_go_screen()
```

Tilemap.py

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *

class Map:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = []
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.data.append(line.strip())

        self.tilewidth = len(self.data[0])
        self.tileheight = len(self.data)
        self.width = self.tilewidth * TILESIZE
        self.height = self.tileheight * TILESIZE

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.x + int(WIDTH / 2)
        y = -target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT / 2)

        # limit scrolling to map size
        x = min(0, x)  # left
        y = min(0, y)  # top
        x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x)  # right
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y)  # bottom
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

De antemano muchas gracias